# .Net Core Identity Unit Testing - Add Data To Mocked UserStore

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, asp.net-identity, moq

I'm currently trying to unit test my `Auth` service that uses `UserManager` and `Role Manager` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`.  I have a few tests up and running by using the code below.  I mock the `UserStore` but don't add any data to it.

```
var dbContextMock = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(
    new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);

var mockRoleManager = new Mock<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>(
    new Mock<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>().Object,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);

var authService = new AuthService(dbContextMock.Object, mockRoleManager.Object, mockUserManager.Object, Configuration);

mockUserManager
    .Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user" });

mockUserManager
    .Setup(x => x.RemoveClaimAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>(), It.IsAny<Claim>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => IdentityResult.Success);

Ack ack = await authService.DeleteClaim(new dtoClaim { Type = "Type", Value = "Value" });

Assert.IsNotNull(ack.StatusMessage);
```

I have an another test that gets and returns all the `Users` by

```
IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
```

So, is there a way I get mock `userManager.Users`?

I've tried

```
mockUserManager
    .Setup(x => x.Users)
    .ReturnsAsync(userList);
```

But get the error

`ISetup<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, IQueryable<ApplicationUser>>` does not contain a definition for `ReturnsAsync`

Also, Question 2. Is there a way I can initialize the mocked UserStore by adding a list of `Users` to it then have the User Manager refer to that user store instead of me having to manually return the list in the `ReturnsAsync`

So, instead of

```
mockUserManager
    .Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user" });
```

use

```
mockUserManager
    .Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => Code here to actually run FindByIdAsync against UserStore);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.Returns(...` instead of `.ReturnsAsync(...`?

Comment: @DavidG If I use `Returns` I get the error Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.  `ReturnsAsync` seems to be working fine.

Comment: *does not contain a definition for ReturnsAsync* suggests that it isn't working fine.

Comment: @DavidG Thats only if I use `x.Users`.  Using other methods like `FindByIdAsync` work fine.  Which is part of my question.

Comment: But `x.Users` isn't an async method so it has to be `.Returns`. Your problem may be that your `userList` object isn't an `IQueryable`. Perhaps you need to do `userList.AsQueryable()` instead?